# Please show bounty message in Android bounty details pop-up

Tags: feature-request, android-app, bounties, bounty-remarks

In the android app, looking at bounty details using the *i* button, the bounty reasons are not shown:

> [image]

The bounty message can provide important information as to the setter's requirements (who may not be the OP and therefore does not wish to edit the question to do so).